# groovy : get latest json file in directory

Tags: sorting, groovy, filter

I would like to get latest JSON file from `/tmp` directory using Groovy. I can get latest file OR I can filter on `.json` extension :

```
def file = new File( '/tmp' ).listFiles()?.sort { -it.lastModified() }?.head()
def file = new File('/tmp').listFiles().find{it.isFile() && it=~/.json$/}.head()
```

How can I do both ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding `.findAll {}` to your first example, something like:

```
def file = new File( '/tmp' )
        .listFiles()
        .findAll { it.file && it.name.endsWith('.json') }
        .sort { -it.lastModified() }
        .first()
```

`findAll()` works similarly to `find()`, however it returns a list of elements that match given predicate, while `find()` returns a first or any element that matches the predicate.

You may also consider using `.getAt(0)` instead of `.first()` or `.head()` method that will throw an exception if the list is empty. `.getAt(0)` will simply return `null` in this case.

```
def file = new File('/tmp')
        .listFiles()
        .findAll { it.file && it.name.endsWith('.json') }
        .sort { -it.lastModified() }
        .getAt(0)
```